# Using Rails CRUD generator to generate custom files under custom folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I want to add some extra folders and file when Rails 4 CRUD generator is trigger

I know that Rails CRUD Generator generate files under

- controller (folder)
- model (folder) and
- View (folder)

What I want is to add extra files in custom folders

- controller (folder)
- model (folder) and
- View (folder)
- MyCustomFolder --> a file , b file.

Is that possible?

Comment: Take a look at this to create your custom generators: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: I did , I am still having troubles sorting things out